# Combining data from cells on a large scale

Tags: excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet that contains over 2000 rows.  Of those rows, I need to combine  columns D299/E299 through D2032/E2032 together.  In additional, I need to add () around the data that is coming from the E column.

If it makes things easier, I can create a new workbook with only the two columns of data and paste the modified data in afterward.

[image: Here's what it looks like now.]

[image: This is the desired final product.]

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula in a helper column

```
=D299&" ("&E299&")"
```

copy down, then copy the result and paste special > Values over the data in column D